# Why won't composer use OPcache?

Tags: php, composer-php, opcache

I added

```
"require": {
    "ext-opcache": "*",
```

to `composer.json` for an eDirectory Symfony 2.8 app, but it gave me an error:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-opcache * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's opcache extension.
```

However, I *do* have OPcache installed!

```
$ php -r "phpinfo();" | grep OPcache -a3
Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching => Up and Running
Optimization => Enabled
```

It doesn't complain about `"ext-gd": "*"` or `"ext-mbstring": "*"`.

PHP 5.6.27

Comment: Can we get output of `composer show -p`?

Comment: try to reinstall composer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The extension name is `Zend OPcache` not `OPcache`. You need to require it with full name:

```
"ext-zend-opcache": "*"
```